# find sum by removing first character from string in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

input_table

```
username  input
A         A10
B         A9
C         A8
D         A7
E         A0
F         A4
```

like so on

How i can find sum of input by removing 'A' char from 'input' field

Comment: Maybe [SUBSTRING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the below code

```
select SUM(SUBSTRING(input, 2)) from input_table
```

Comment: Don't you have to cast it as a number first?

Comment: @DanBracuk, That can also be done. But if it is sure to remove only the first character to get a number, then casting is not necessary

Comment: @Anand, With pleasure. Can you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 3):

Try this, may work;)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6db6a/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema**:

```
CREATE TABLE input_table
    (`username` varchar(1), `input` varchar(3))
;

INSERT INTO input_table
    (`username`, `input`)
VALUES
    ('A', 'A10'),
    ('B', 'A9'),
    ('C', 'A8'),
    ('D', 'A7'),
    ('E', 'A0'),
    ('F', 'A4')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select sum(replace(input, 'A', '')) from input_table
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6db6a/2/0)**:

```
| sum(replace(input, 'A', '')) |
|------------------------------|
|                           38 |
```

Comment: Thanx for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Use `RIGHT` function to get the number in the right side and `CAST` it and then find the `SUM`.

**Query**

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(RIGHT(input, LENGTH(input) - 1) AS UNSIGNED)) AS `SUM`
FROM input_table;
```

Comment: While this will work, it lacks the simplicity of the other two answers.

Comment: @DanBracuk : Just an other perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Try this also:

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(TRIM(LEADING 'A' FROM input)) AS UNSIGNED) AS total FROM table;
```